# Creating an unsigned .xcarchive from Xamarin

Tags: ios, xamarin, msbuild, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I need to create an unsigned .xcarchive file of my Xamarin iOS app. At the moment we're using Azure DevOps Pipeline to build the .xcarchive with the task `XamariniOS@1` and am passing the input `args: '/p:ArchiveOnBuild=true /t:"Build"'`, however the client tells me this is still signed.

How can I either

1. Pass an argument to not sign the .xcarchive
2. Modify the .xcarchive after the fact to 'unsign' it. With an .ipa I think you can remove the code signature folder, is the same applicable here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doesn't look like this is possible.